# Can we declare a struct as conforming to a concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

With concepts we can require template parameters to conform to a concept, e.g. in:

```
template<ForwardIterator A>
struct S { A a; };
```

we parametrize the `struct S` with a type `A` which we require to conform to the concept `ForwardIterator`. Then we can instantiate `S<std::vector<int>::iterator>` but not, for example `S<std::vector<int>>`.

My question pertains to the definition of a concrete type `T` that would be used in place of `A` in the above case: *Can we declare a type `T` to conform to `ForwardIterator` already at the time of its definition, without instantiating `S<T>`?

Comment: I *just* came back as I realized I was using "template introduction". Thanks, I'll update. The rest of the question still stands, but I clarified I mean a concrete type `T` to be used in place of `A`.

Comment: My question could perhaps be understood as asking for an equivalent of `class T implements ForwardIterator` in Java, with the intent that the compiler verifies immediately, whether I'm fulfilling the concept requirements.

Comment: You should not conflate Java Interfaces or base classes with C++ concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `concept` definition creates constant expression template. Since an instantiation of a concept is constant expression, you can use it in a `static_assert` statement. So if you have declared some type `T` and at some point want to verify that it fits into a concept `C` based on all accessible declarations, then you can do `static_assert(C<T>);`.

Of course, many concepts are not so simple. Many concepts constrain multiple parameters; they express the relationship between multiple types or whatever. You shouldn't limit your thinking about concepts in such an OOP/inheritance fashion.

Comment: Your answer applies perfectly to the more general usage of concepts that you mention: `static_assert(C1<T,U,V,W> && C2<T,U>)` -- this is exactly what I need. I'm glad my effort to reduce the complexity of my actual problem and to simplify the question before asking didn't go unnoticed :P